# How to make 2 divs to fill 100% viewport height

Tags: height, viewport

To specify my question in detail, I have 2 divs. One of them is the main navigation and below my navigation I have a carousel (bootstrap). I want the carousel to fit perfectly to the bottom of the page when the user visits the page. Just for the aesthetics sake. I know I can set the height of the carousel to be e.g. 400px but each device's screen is different and I think it will look more professional and polished if the carousel's bottom will fit to the bottom of the screen regardless of the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider taking advantage of [CSS's viewport-based units](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/viewport.html) like `vh` and `vw`, which use a percentage of the available viewport width and height respectively :

```
.your-carousel {
    /* This will occupy 100% of the available viewport */
    height: 100vh;
}
```

This is supported in [most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), so if you are already using Bootstrap, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes I know about those viewport-based units but it doesn't work if I have 2 divs (one stacked on top of another) I want the div on the bottom to fill the rest of available space. Have a look at my html below.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my html by the way:

    <body>

    <!-- nav -->
    <div class="container">
        <a id="logo" class="font-raleway text-center" href="#">Denley</a>
        <br>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default bold">

            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WOMEN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SHOES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SALE OFF</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">COLLECTIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
                <div class="col-xs-3 icons"><img src="images/icons/account.png"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 icons"><img src="images/icons/wish_list.png"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 icons"><img id="cart-icon" src="images/icons/cart.png"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 icons"><img src="images/icons/search.png"></div>
            </div>  
        </div><!-- /col-xs-12 -->
    </div><!-- /row -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/test.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          ...
        </div>
    </div>
  ...
  </div><!-- /carousel-inner -->

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
```